# Will loading an old saved game lose any progress?

Tags: fallout-4, xbox-one

I want to go back and complete the alternative endings in Fallout 4, however I'm reluctant in case I lose my progress.

**Does loading an old game then saving my progress on an alternate timeline have any affect on my current saved progress?**

Don't want to lose it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they will not overwrite.  The thing you want to do is find something unique, like a person, or an object to look at when you save, so you can remember where you were if you want to go back to a different save.  Otherwise you will just be guessing.

Comment: +1, this really helps with the lack of file names mentioned in comments on the other answer. All my saves constitute photo albums of my characters' adventures. I'll often save at a significant point just to get a good picture of it. If you use the 3rd person camera to rotate before saving, it saves the picture from that angle, so you can easily get your character in the shot.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is.... Drum Roll Please! (Patatatatatatatatatataaaa)... no. As long as you are careful to load the previous save and save a separate save file when you complete the alternate ending, and you don't overwrite your previous saves, it will not affect your current game whatsoever.

Comment: +1 If only bethesda allowed us to rename files.  I did this and found it helpful to keep a note on my phone with the exact file name and a description of the major saves.  Makes it a lot easier to go back and forth between play throughs

Comment: @rlord3534 Yeah! I did the same thing, but with notepad on my computer.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing it will affect is autosave files, as any autosaves will start to be overwritten with the content of the save you're playing on. Hard saves are completely unaffected.